# Type error: '_' is declared but its value is never read

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

On my Next.JS project with TypeScript I cannot run build since I have `Type error: '_' is declared but its value is never read.`

I try to set "noUnusedLocals" to false in my tsconfig but I keep the same error in my build

```
  useScrollPosition(
    ({ _, currPos }: any) => {
      const isShow = currPos.y > -100
      if (isShow !== hideOnScroll) setHideOnScroll(isShow)
    },
    [hideOnScroll],
    null,
    false,
    null
  )
```

Comment: Why are you using `_` there at all? If you only need to destructure `currPos` from the parameter, just do `{ currPos }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using `_` you can just omit it when you destructure the object. Try

```
useScrollPosition(
  ({ currPos }: any) => {
    const isShow = currPos.y > -100
    if (isShow !== hideOnScroll) setHideOnScroll(isShow)
  },
  [hideOnScroll],
  null,
  false,
  null
)
```